# Stop Chrome Launching Bookmarks in The Background

Tags: networking, google-chrome, bookmarks

As the title suggests, my Chrome is launching bookmarks in the background (to be clear, there isn't a window popping up), and it's causing connection issues, and I'd like to stop it.

How do I know this is happening? I have a bookmark that runs a query that emails relevant people, it is only used once or twice a year. On Jan 15, 2024 @ 8:02 I received the email, and originally figured I had an open window that took a long time to open, I didn't have a window open.

I then checked my server logs for a potential intruder, and what I found was that the query was executed from my IP address. I installed a network monitoring software, and scanned my computer for malware/viruses, which turned out clean.

I forgot about it until this morning Jan 17, 2024 @ 9:20 another email was sent out. I check the logs, and once again, it showed my IP address as the sending IP.

I further researched, and in the network monitoring software, it showed a connection to my site (which I didn't have open) at the time the email was sent.

I'm open to other suggestions as to what is going on, I did have this page bookmarked, and it had been months since I last used the link, leaving the most probable cause as Chrome opening my bookmarks in the background. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Is Chrome reopening these bookmarks when you reopen the browser?

Comment: Is your Chrome Profile launching the bookmarks. What you have is not happening here with Chrome newest.

Comment: @Music2myear No, chrome isn't opening these bookmarks at least not in the window, they're being run in the background. I was on a completely different application when it happened the second time (a non chromium application), my computer had been on for over an hour when it ran the bookmark.